# Vim - how to exclude part of clipboard register when pasting

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have the following aliases:

```
map <C-F> <Esc>/<C-R><C-W><CR>N
map <S-F> <Esc>/\<<C-R><C-W>\><CR>N
```

These allow me to quickly search for a string as either a part of as a complete word. After doing this I often end up pasting the contents of @/ (C-R, /), i.e. my last search using these aliases, into another vim command (vimgrep, s//g, etc.).

If I use C-F this works great, since @/ contains the string what I searched for (example: " foo"). But when I use S-F, @/ includes "\<" and "\>" (example: "\< foo\>"), which I pretty much always end up deleting manually.

Is there a way to have "\<" and "\>" be removed automagically from the @/ register?

Comment: At which point you would remove these characters from `@/`? If you remove them too early them you affect your searches. You could paste into other commands (vimgrep, s//g) using a mapping, or save the return of `<C-R><C-W>` into a different register (say `f`), and them use `<C-R>f` to retrieve it on the next command.

Comment: I would like to remove the characters when I paste. Ideally the register would *keep* the </> characters, but what gets pasted would not have them. I guess I **could** save `<C-R><C-W>` into a different register and use that, but would be great if there's a solution that maintains usage of `@/`, and just edits what gets read from it during a paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the command-line `<C-r>/` command, or add a variant `<C-r>?`, like this:

```
:cnoremap <C-r>? <C-r>=substitute(@/, '\\[<>]', '' ,'g')<CR>
```